# Both ts-ls and eslint used for typescript in lsp-mode. Possible to use eslint with `lsp-format-buffer`?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, typescript

I have both [ts-ls](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-typescript/) and [eslint](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-eslint/) backends enabled for typescript buffers and they both seem to work well for linting, prompting, etc. However, I would like `lsp-format-buffer` to use eslint, not ts-ls. How can I do it?